# Releasing of updated version of app in itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, release

If I upload a new version of my app to the App Store, what will happen to the older version of my app i.e present in the app store?
Will the older version get removed from the app store or it is removed only after the new version(updated app) is approved by the itune team?

Comment: The current version is replaced by the newly uploaded ipa only after it gets approved by the review team.

Answer (score 0):

The new version will only replace the existing one in the AppStore after the review went through and depending on your app configuration:

1. either have the release become available immediately if you have this option selected

[image]
 2. you have to manually release the version, by pressing the Release this version button, if you have the first option selected.
[image]